# SQL query, select from 2 tables random

Tags: sql, mysql, random

Hello all i have a problem that i just CANT get to work like i what it..

i want to show news and reviews (2 tables) and i want to have random output and not the same output

here is my query i really hope some one can explain me what i do wrong

```
SELECT
                anmeldelser.billed_sti ,
                anmeldelser.overskrift ,
                anmeldelser.indhold ,
                anmeldelser.id ,
                anmeldelser.godkendt
            FROM
                anmeldelser
            LIMIT 0,6
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                nyheder.id ,
                nyheder.billed_sti ,
                nyheder.overskrift ,
                nyheder.indhold ,
                nyheder.godkendt
            FROM nyheder
            ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,6
```

Comment: please be more specific about "i want to have random output and not the same output", I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

First off it looks like the column order for the two `SELECT` statements don't match which they need to for a UNION.

What does the following return?

```
        SELECT
            anmeldelser.billed_sti ,
            anmeldelser.overskrift ,
            anmeldelser.indhold ,
            anmeldelser.id ,
            anmeldelser.godkendt
        FROM
            anmeldelser
        LIMIT 0,6
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            nyheder.billed_sti ,
            nyheder.overskrift ,
            nyheder.indhold ,
            nyheder.id ,
            nyheder.godkendt
        FROM nyheder
        ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,6
```

(which RDBMS are you using? the SQL you have is not valid for Sybase but there may be techniques depending on the 'flavour' of SQL you are using)

Comment: im using mysql, you can see here what i got out http://tinyurl.com/37kzdtt
if you refresh they show something random, BUT its all the same

Comment: oh this is a problem in your display loop... you are not going to the next row

Comment: @klaus : exactly -- you don't include the rest of the code but $query is the same each time... you have to do a fetch row or next between them -- depending on what library you are using.

Comment: @Hogan i have do a foreach and it work now :) but how can i tjek if it from the news tabel or review tabel? cause i cant people to "read more" so i need to find out if i need to link to the news page or review page :S

Comment: @klaus : look at my example for how to do this -- you "create" a new column in the select statement with the type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the first table is not selecting random elements

```
SELECT temp.* FROM
(
  SELECT
    anmeldelser.id ,
    anmeldelser.billed_sti ,
    anmeldelser.overskrift ,
    anmeldelser.indhold ,
    anmeldelser.godkendt,
    'News' as artType
  FROM anmeldelser
  UNION 
  SELECT
    nyheder.id ,
    nyheder.billed_sti ,
    nyheder.overskrift ,
    nyheder.indhold ,
    nyheder.godkendt,
    'Review' as artType
  FROM nyheder
 ) temp
 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,6
```

Comment: @klaus : I forgot to alias the sub-query, try the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Since RAND() appears only in the ORDER BY clause, would it not only be evaluated once for the whole query, and not once per row?

Comment: yes thats the problem it only take effect on the whole query, and i need to be per row